# Using ajax to call a php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a main page in my app called index.php where i want to show some photos. Code in that file is:

```
<div id="main" name="main">
    <input type="button" value="Photos" onclick="showIm()">
</div>
```

File function.php contains a function to show photos on the screen:

```
function showPhotos()
{
    global $link;
    $result = pg_query_params($link, 'SELECT photo_name FROM photos');
    while($photos_row = pg_fetch_row($result))
    {

    echo '<a href="photos/'.$photos_row[0].'">
    <img src="photos/'.$photos_row[0].'"></a>';
    }   
}
```

My last file is function.js where i try to call showPhotos using ajax

```
function showIm()
{
 $.ajax({
  url: "functions.php"
})
}
```

So inside the last function I want to call showPhotos() to get the results. I think that my implementation is a little complicated but I would like to know if anyone could help.

Comment: when you make an ajax call, it is exactly the same as loading a normal PHP page -- the browser requests a URL, and the URL responds with the result. You can't simply call a PHP function directly via ajax and more than you can via a normal URL; there has to be a PHP program that acts as the entry point and then makes a call to the appropriate function. If you're using a PHP framework then this kind of thing will be handled for you; if not, then you'll need to write the PHP ajax call handler program yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to do something with that result! Add a `success` method and declare a return `dataType`

```
function showIm()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            //do something with the response here
            //the "html" variable will contain your PHP response
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: But functions.php contains many functions. How do i call function showPhotos()?